# Values input in html form not taken by php

Tags: php, html

I tried to execute the following html code:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Listing 9.1 A simple HTML form</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action="listing.php" method="POST">
 <p><strong>Name:</strong><br>
 <input type="text" name="user"></p>
 <p><strong>Address:</strong><br>
 <textarea name="address" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea></p>
 <p><input type="submit" value="send"></p>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And this is the code of the associated php file (listing.php):

```
     <html>
 <head>
 <title>Listing  Reading input from a form </title>
 </head>
 <body>

 Welcome <?php echo $_POST["user"]; ?><br>
 Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["address"]; ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I was able to get the form and enter values as shown below:
 [Form Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd4Kf.jpg)

But, when I clicked 'Send Message', it displays only:
Welcome 
Your email address is:

Without the values that I entered through the form.

When I tried to run the php file directly from the local host (http://localhost/listing.php), I received these error messages:
Welcome 
Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\listing.php on line 7

Your email address is: 
Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\listing.php on line 8

I even modified the php code as follows, but still got the same output:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Listing  Reading input from a form </title>
 </head>
 <body>

 Welcome <?php 
  if(isset($_POST['submit'];)) {
  session_start(); 
  $user = $_POST['user'];
  echo "$text";}else {echo 'Could not load text!';}?><br>
 Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["address"]; ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I would really appreciate it if you could give some advice to make it work.
 Thanks

Comment: use this  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) instead of  if(isset($_POST['submit'];))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: Another issue I possibly think is going on here is that if ALL your files are not in the `htdocs` directory of `xampp`, you should use `http://localhost/listing.php` in the form action. Like this `<form action="http://localhost/listing.php" ....>`

Answer (score 0):

if(isset($_POST['submit'];)) should be changed,so you check if address and user is isset. Furthermore you normally don't want ; in your if statements.

Here i have a optimized version for you. the !empty is added so we also check if the inputs are not empty.

```
if (isset($_POST["name"] && isset($_POST["address"])) {
  if (!empty($_POST["name"] && !empty($_POST["address"]) {
    // execute code as u would 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\listing.php on line 8

This is caused by the use of the ';' in the if condition.
Remove that and you should be good. for now.

Try this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Listing  Reading input from a form </title>
</head>
<body>

Welcome <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
  {
      session_start(); 
      $user = $_POST['user'];
      echo $user;
      echo "<br><br>Your Email Address is: ".$_POST['address'];
  }
  else 
  {
     echo 'Could not load text!';
  }
 ?>
 <br>



<form action="" method="POST">
<p><strong>Name:</strong><br>
<input type="text" name="user"></p>
<p><strong>Address:</strong><br>
<textarea name="address" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="send" name="submit"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code worked, but it displays the entered value along with form itself. I don't need the form to be  displayed again with the output. Also, the code works as a combined file. When I split html and php codes into two files, it gives this output: Welcome 
Your Email Address is: ".$_POST['address']; } else { echo 'Could not load text!'; } ?>  --- any more tips would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your second code block `$text` isn't defined anywhere. Do you mean to have `$user`?

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Listing Reading input from a form</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 Welcome 
 <?php 
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     session_start(); 
     echo isset($_POST['user']) ? $_POST['user'] : "User";
   } else {
     echo "User";
   } 
 ?>
 <br>
 Your email address is: 
 <?php 
    echo isset($_POST["address"]) ? $_POST["address"] : "Address" 
 ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your code, but I got the same results: Welcome 
Your email address is:  ; that's only the comments, without the values that I entered in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    echo "Welcome ".$user;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Your email address is: ".$_POST["address"];
  }else {
    // you may get rid of this block if you like
    echo 'Could not load text!';
  }

?>

    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Listing 9.1 A simple HTML form</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
          <p><strong>Name:</strong><br>
          <input type="text" name="user"></p>
          <p><strong>Address:</strong><br>
          <textarea name="address" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea></p>
          <p><input type="submit" name='submit' value="send"></p>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I tried your code, and this is what I got: "; echo "Your email address is: ".$_POST["address"]; }else { echo 'Could not load text!'; } ?>

Comment: @Faresfox: I have edited my answer. Let me know if it works now.